# cordova: restart the server on local in dev mode

Tags: cordova

I'm used to ionic for mobile, now I'm trying `cordova` for a new project and I don't understand something: why should I restart the server manually each time I change something in a file? Is there any way to automatically restart the server while in development mode using this command `cordova run browser` ?

Thanks.